# Assign username to field in models.py table

Tags: django, authentication, django-models, django-views, django-forms

Let’s say I have a Table1 that contains 5 data,

```
> class Table1(models.Model):
>     code     = models.CharField(max_length=16,unique=True)
> 
>     author_Up    = models.CharField(max_length=16,default=User)
>     date_Up      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
>     post_date    = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
>     author       = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
>     def __str__(self):
>         return self.code
```

I am using formes.py as:

```
class Table1_F(forms.ModelForm):
    code = forms.CharField(label='Code',max_length=16)
    class Meta:
        model= Table1
        fields=['code']
```

The Problem is I need to assign a new values of (author_Up) and (date_Up) every time that another user make an update and keep the initial author.

How do I solve this Please?

Comment: Share the relevant view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise to work with a `ForeignKey` to refer to the autohr, and furthermore work with `auto_now_add` for the `post_date` field:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Table1(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=16,unique=True)
    author_Up = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='updated_posts',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    date_Up = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='written_posts',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.code
```

In the `UpdateView`, we can now update the user model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import UpdateView

class MyUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Table1
    form = Table1_F

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author_Up = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

In the `CreateView`, we can set the `author`, and the `authorUp` if necessary:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import CreateView

class MyUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Table1
    form = Table1_F  # might be another form

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author_Up = self.request.user
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: Wouldn't it be best to do this on the ModelForm rather than the view? If you have other views using the same form, you'll have to do it manually every time.

Comment: @MarcCompte: normally forms are request unaware, while you can of course override the `ModelForm` logic to use the request object (or the user object), I'm not sure that this is a good idea, since it makes the form request aware, and less reusable to use it for example for a scheduled task.

Comment: I see your point. I guess it depends on each one's setup and the features you use. I'd still prefer to do some checks on the form to see if one needs to override the user fields or not. But if you only have one view using this form, this would be suitable as well.

Comment: Hi I just want to add a function into the models.py to calculate how much days before the last updating day, but I have some problems with?

    def get_date(self):
        today = datetime.datetime.date()
        days  = self.date_Up
        daysDiff = (today-days)
        return daysDiff

Comment: `return (datetime.date.today()-self.date_Up).days`

Comment: didn't worked 
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.date' and 'datetime.datetime'

Comment: use `datetime.datetime.now()` instead of `datetime.date.today()`.

Comment: Nope it gives me this error: (can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes)

Comment: @tibas: ah, then you need to `from django.utils.timezone import now` in the head of the file, and use `(now()-self.date_Up).days` in the expression.